# Maven property referencing a list

Tags: maven

I am working with a (custom, internally developed, details do not matter here) Maven plugin which takes a list of names, like this:

```
<configuration>
    <names>
        <name>Alice</name>
        <name>Bob</name>
        <name>Joe</name>
        <name>Sally</name>
    </names>
    ...
```

The list is hard-coded in the POM file.

I'd like to have something a little more dynamic, so that I can use a user-defined variable to specify a single name. I can do it this way:

> mvn clean package -Dname=Bob

```
<configuration>
    <names>
        <name>${name}</name>
    </names>
```

The problem is that the only way I've found so far to do this is to have two profiles with duplicate plugin configurations: one with the pre-defined list, and one with the single user-defined value:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>default</id>
        ...
        <configuration>
          <names>
              <name>Alice</name>
              <name>Bob</name>
              <name>Joe</name>
              <name>Sally</name>
          </names>
        ...
  </profile>

  <profile>
    <id>single-value</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>name</name>
      </property> 
    </activation>
    ...
      <configuration>
        <names>
          <name>${name}</name>
        </names>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

This works, but my problem with it is that both profiles have almost completely identical configurations (and they are rather lengthy configurations as well) for this plugin, *except for the list of names*.

What I'd like to do is have a Maven property contain a list, rather than a single value. Something like this:

```
<project>
  <properties>
    <names>
      <name>bob</name>
    </names>
  </properties>
  ...
```

So that my `single-value` profile will simple redefine the `names` property. But of course, this doesn't work so easily: the code sample above produces a non-parseable POM error.

Is there any way to do what I want with some other Maven plugin, or trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a parameter which takes a comma-separated value. In your code, translate this String to a List of Strings. You should really wonder if you want this to be set by commandline or if it is sufficient enough to do it only in the plugin configuration. The latter is preferred of course. 
Just as a small example: see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/site-mojo.html#locales

Comment: I agree that would be simpler, except the plugin is designed to take a *list*, not a comma-separated string. It's not a bad idea but changes to the plugin are somewhat out of scope in this situation.

Comment: In that case just introduce a new parameter. Ensure that the values of both parameters are merged or that only 1 is used (else throw MojoFailureException).

Comment: Also a good idea, but again, changes to the plugin are out of scope. It could be done, but that raises other issues. If I can show there is absolutely *no* other way to do it, then I can probably get the plugin changed.

Comment: There's no other way. In fact, when the plugin-descriptor is created, it should check if it makes sense to expose it as a property. Lists are useless. I'll create an issue for this.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think *I* can create the issue since it's our own plugin. ;)